# Can't I log errors of released flash or actionscript application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, exception, error-handling, error-logging

I want to log all error messages and call stacks of my application if it causes errors after I released the application to the web site.
I will save the logs on files on the web server.

In debug player `Error.message` contains a detailed error message and `Error.getStackTrace()` returns call stack:

```
message: Error #1006: cccc is not a function.

stack trace:
 TypeError: Error #1006: cccc is not a function.
 at f()[/source/Main.as:38]
```

But in normal player which users of my application use, `Error.message` contains only error code and `Error.getStackTrace()` returns null:

```
message: Error #1006

stack trace: null
```

In other web application written with languages like javascript, PHP or ruby, I always log errors or stack trace.
But in actionscript or flash application, can't I know where and why errors occur after releasing it?

Is it normal to save logs of errors in released flash applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between Release mode and Debug mode is that all debug infos are removed from the released swf. Therefore, if you compile your swf in release, it will be lighter, faster and won't be able to show you why specifically it crashed.

To achieve what you want to do, you should then compile in debug mode and set a variable through the HTML context or FlashPlayer capabilities to catch every error and log it instead of throwing it.

Comment: thanks. 
But both 2 examples in my question are the results of the swf which was compiled in debug mode.
The first example is the result of debug player and the second example is the result of normal player.
Not release mode and debug mode.